# Process.Start throws "system cannot find the file specified" error

Tags: c#

I am working on a project and have the code. I am trying to redirect the output from a command line app to a textbox. Here is the code i currently have;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"‪‪C:\rar.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = RarName + " " + RarType;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    p.Start();

    StreamReader outputWriter = p.StandardOutput;
    String errorReader = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    String line = outputWriter.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        textBox3.Text = line;
        line = outputWriter.ReadLine();
    }
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

The code seems to be alright, but when I click the button it just gives an "system cannot find file specified" error on the `p.Start();`. I have checked, the file exists on the C drive.

Here's a list of all the things I've done:

- Use both x86 and x64 versions of the program
- Change the architechture from any cpu to x64
- Tried moving the application elsewhere
- Tried changing shellexecute to false

but none of those have worked. What is the problem here?

Comment: Have a look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/xLd4Q - there seems to be a invisible characters

Comment: updated version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KDgQnw - this character: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm

Comment: @RandRandom thank you, invisible characters like that are quite annoying..